# Bootstrap navigation logo on center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to design a centered logo navigation but i have some output problems

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #231f20;
  min-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 96px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    line-height: 126px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 24px;
  } 
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  } 
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    padding: 0 50px;
  } 
}
```

/////

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SC9LKtA.png" alt="Brand" width="180" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="./about-us">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="./menu">Our Food</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SC9LKtA.png" alt="Brand" width="180" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="./book">Book a Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="./promotions">Promotions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: The same display error can be seen at codepen also]

Also, demo at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egqxjW

What is the problem that is causing that white space?

PS: Is there a better way to get the same result? What should i do to include the logo only once in the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`right: -50%;` moved the `ul` 50% to the right of where it should be. Its width stay the same (100% of the container), and it's moved by 50% to the right, so 50% of the `ul` is outside of the container, bleeding out of screen.

I made some change to achieve the same result you want, using `text-align: center` and `display: inline-block` instead. They are marked with /* change */ in the CSS.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

.navbar {
  background-color: #231f20;
  min-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 96px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    /* change */
    text-align: center;
    /* change */
  }
  ul.navbar-nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /* change */
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
  }
  ul.navbar-nav>li a {
    line-height: 126px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 24px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav>li a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-nav>li a {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SC9LKtA.png" alt="Brand" width="180" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="./about-us">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="./menu">Our Food</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SC9LKtA.png" alt="Brand" width="180" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./book">Book a Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="./promotions">Promotions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello, as you can see in your demo code , the header is no longer centered.

Comment: Stackoverflow's not loading bootstrap's CSS well. See this codepen I cloned from you with the same changes I made: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRMYOL

Comment: Thank you. That is what i was looking for. Now, for the second question, is there a way to have just one logo in the html and when on small size screen to be centered?

Answer (score 0):

You have in your style a rule which is setting `right: -50%` on the navbar.  Unfortunately, since the UL navbar displays as a block you wind up with an element that is 100% moving to the right 50% and winding up offscreen.

Instead of messing with right relative positioning you should try the `navbar-right` bootstrap class.  Like so:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Most of the layouts from bootstrap play with floats, so you can't just use relative positioning expecting it to behave the same way.

Lastly you should compare it with the official documentation responsive navbar example here: https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

You can see the resulting example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdQJRb

Comment: What i wa trying to do was centering the navbar, not align it to right.

Comment: Then all you needed to do was set a specific `width` even in percentage and set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` on the container you wanted to center.

Comment: Thank you for this, is there a way to have just one logo in the html and when on small size screen to be centered?